# How does Facebook handle a failure to connect to an app-provided real-time update URL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time-updates

Reference: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/

When a subscription has been created for real-time updates of some sort (say user properties, for instance), what happens if the provided callback URL is unreachable?

There are a few sub-cases here:

1. Failure to reach the callback URL at subscription verification;
2. Subscription verification succeeds but the callback URL becomes unreachable at some later time when attempting a change notification.

It's mainly #2 that interests me.  Does the notification go into a retry queue?  If so, how many retries are attempted, and over what time span?  Is there any way to query for "missed" notifications?  Is there different handling for different failure modes (host name lookup, host unreachable, port closed, error return code in the HTTP response)?

Answer (score 1):

The very page that I linked in the question provides this answer:

> If a change notification to your server fails, Facebook will retry again immediately, then a few times more, with decreasing frequency, over the next 24 hours.

Not as much detail as I had hoped for, but probably good enough.